# How to save the values of input field from html to file that will be separted by comas

Tags: php, html

HTML page consists of one input field named "number". It redirects to php page where i am storing the data in file.

But the data in file storing in the following manner: 98765. But i want to store the numbers separated by comas. eg: 9,8,7,6 and i want to store in an array.

My PHP code:

```
<?php 
$number=$_POST['number'];

if(isset($_POST['number']))

{

  $data =  $_POST['number'] . "\n";

  file_put_contents('data_file.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}

$text = file_get_contents('data_file.txt',true);

//$words = str_word_count($text, 1);

$a1 = explode(',',$txt);

print_r($a1);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

`$data = $_POST['number'] . "\n";`

to

`$data = $_POST['number'] . ",";`
?